# How can I use cypher to return some limited amount of nodes, and a count of all nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I currently have this query:

```
START n=node(*) 
MATCH (p:Person)-[:is_member]->(g:Group) 
WHERE g.name ='FooManGroup' 
RETURN p, count(p)
LIMIT 5
```

Say there are 42 people in `FooManGroup`, I want to return 5 of these people, with a count of 42.

Is this possible to do in one query?

Running this now returns 5 rows, which is fine, but a count of 104, which is the total number of nodes of any type in my DB.

Any suggestions?

Comment: FYI, you aren't using `n` from the start clause, which is going to totally ruin your counts (they'll be multiplied by count(n)).

Comment: @WesFreeman Good point, modified my answer with the `START` clause.

Comment: You cannot return p and count(p) at the same time, you would have to run the match twice or use a collect() grouping function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `WITH` clause to do the counting of the persons, followed by an identical `MATCH` clause to do the matching of each person. Notice that you need to `START` on the `p` nodes and not just some `n` that will match any node in the graph:

```
MATCH (p:Person )-[:is_member]->(g:Group)
WHERE g.name ='FooManGroup' 
WITH count(p) as personsInGroup
MATCH (p:Person)-[:is_member]->(g:Group)
WHERE g.name ='FooManGroup'
RETURN p, personsInGroup
LIMIT 5
```

It may not be the best or most elegant way to this, but it works. If you use cypher 2.0 it may be a bit more compact like this:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:is_member]->(g:Group {name: 'FooManGroup'})
WITH count(p) as personsInGroup
MATCH (p:Person)-[:is_member]->(g:Group {name: 'FooManGroup'})
RETURN p, personsInGroup
LIMIT 5
```

Relationship types are always uppercased in cypher, so `:is_member` should be `:IS_MEMBER` which I think is more readable:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:IS_MEMBER]->(g:Group {name: 'FooManGroup'})
WITH count(p) as personsInGroup
MATCH (p:Person)-[:IS_MEMBER]->(g:Group {name: 'FooManGroup'})
RETURN p, personsInGroup
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: The first query in this answer still uses the `START` clause with `node(*)`, which shouldn't really be used at all in Neo4j 2.0 - and it's clearly Neo4j 2.0 because it also uses node labels. Also - relationship types are case sensitive - it's just idiomatic to use upper case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:is_member]->(g:Group) 
WHERE g.name ='FooManGroup' 
RETURN count(p), collect(p)[0..5]
```

Comment: That will work, since only aggregate functions are used in the `RETURN` clause. It should be noted that this will return a single line, not five.